# hook_apachesolr_process_results having no impact on results

Tags: 7, search

I've posted this at d.o, but I'm hoping maybe someone here might be able to help. (The documentation on apachesolr for D7 is so far rather depressing.)

I wrote a module for a D6 site implementing hook_apachesolr_process_results to modify the snippets of text shown on the search results page. That worked like a charm. We've now moved on the D7. I've again written a module to implement the same hook. This is a lowest-comment-denominator version of the function:

```
function mysearch_apachesolr_process_results(&$results, $query){
  foreach($results as $id => $result){
    $results[$id]['snippet'] = "FOOBAR";
  }
  debug_to_file($results);
}
```

The call at the end debug_to_file is a utility function I use to print_r a variable to a file. That call proves that a) my code *IS* indeed getting run and b) that the $results variable has been changed internally. However, my search results page has nary a `FOOBAR` to be found!

Could it possibly be an interaction between apachesolr and another module? Apachesolr and my theme (fusion 7.x-1.x-dev)?

It'd even be helpful here to get an indication of what to try next as far as debugging. Any advice would be useful!

FTR, I'm using Drupal 7 with the ApacheSolr Search and Framework modules at version 7.x-1.0-beta12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grr. Someone outside of StackExchange suggested a few routes of debugging that would weed out issues having to do with interaction of my code with other code. One of those suggestions was to go back to a default theme and see if my change showed there. It did. I talked to my themer to see if he had any insight.

And, that's when we hit the "a-ha" moment: We were using a custom theme based off of Fusion. (Incidentally, when I switched to stock Fusion, everything worked correctly.) At that point, it was just a matter of flipping through all of the "Appearance" settings to find that under search results none of the checkboxes were ticked. Guess what happened when I ticked the "snippet" checkbox?? Yeah....

Though, we did learn something good here, at least: If you create a new theme as a custom sub-theme of an existing theme, your subtheme does **not** inherit the settings of its parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to implement `hook_preprocess_search_results()`. As for the individual search results themselves, you will be able to use `hook_preprocess_search_result()`. You use the former when you want to modify the block that contains the search results. The later is used when you want to modify each individual result. I rely on them both for my Solr theming in D7.

Comment: What's the benefit to implementing those hooks (are they in the search API?) over implementing the apachesolr-specific hooks?