# Add custom fields to the Apache Solr search results

Tags: 7, search

I'm trying to configure a search page from [Apache Solr module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr), and add some custom fields to the items. Here is the code I'm using for this

Custom module:

```
function hook_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
$query->addParam('fl', 'ts_field_up_short_description');}
```

Function in tamplate.php:

```
function tamplate_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
$variables['ts_field_up_short_description'] = $variables['result']['fields']['ts_field_up_short_description'];}
```

Display field in search-result.tpl.php:

```
<?php if ($ts_field_up_short_description) : ?>
     <?php print $ts_field_up_short_description; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'v created 3 nodes with this field, but only one of them displays the short description field (if displaying the search results with views everything is fine). Please tell me am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forgotten to add the content type filters, everything is correct now. Another (better) way is to modify the snippet in module ([like here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/hook-apachesolr-process-results-having-no-impact-on-results)) instead of the search results template.